# animation in native javascript

Tags: javascript

How do i run an animation(like changing CSS properties) in native javascript without using jQuery library's animate method??
I have tried jQuery library animate and the framerate interval changes to make my animation fluid.
Thanks in advance

Comment: jQuery is open source, why not look at their technique?

Comment: Why not use CSS3 transitions? It's faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4M3ts/1/

```
function animate(object, property, start_value, end_value, time) {
  var frame_rate = 0.06; // 60 FPS
  var frame = 0;
  var delta = (end_value - start_value) / time / frame_rate;
  var handle = setInterval(function() {
    frame++;
    var value = start_value + delta * frame;
    object.style[property] = value + "px";
    if (value == end_value) {
      clearInterval(handle);
    }
  }, 1 / frame_rate);
}

animate(document.getElementById("a"), "top", 0, 100, 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS3 can automatically animate changes to most style properties, using `transition`. It will probably run smoother than you can get with any javascript-based animation.

There's a nice tutorial on how to use it, [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/).

Comment: cross-browser compatibility is an issue that i cant ignore

Comment: Myth busting this one: http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short demonstration:

```
function fade(element, started) {
    if (element.style.opacity > 0){
        console.log(element.style.opacity);
        element.style.opacity -= 0.02;
        setTimeout((function(e){return function(){fade(e);}})(element),10);
    }
}
fade(document.getElementById("myname"));
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6Kzh/1/