# change div with slide on click

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have this code:

```
<a onclick="show('div1')">Show Div 1</a>
<a onclick="show('div2')">Show Div 2</a>`

<div id="div1">This is Div 1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none;">This is hidden Div 2</div>

<script>
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
    function show(divID) {
        var div = document.getElementById(divID);
        currentDiv.style.display = "none";
        div.style.display = "block";
        currentDiv = div;
    }
</script>
```

I wanted to know if i can put transition in this script so that one div fades/slides out while another one fades/slides in.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using jQuery then just replace line **currentDiv.style.display = "none";** with **currendDiv.hide(500)**, provided currentDiv = jQuery("#div1");

Similarly, for div you can have .show(600);

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't know anything about jquery. it would be very helpful if you could give the jquery for my question's javascript.

Comment: As I see you have removed jQuery from your tag, I would suggest you to refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549789/animation-in-native-javascript) for animation effect using native JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');
        
        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: $this.width()
                }, 500);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
    });

});
```

```css
#left, #right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
    <a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
    <a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
    <a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:green">Target 1</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:red">Target 2</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:yellow">Target 3</div>
</div>
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/rs2QK/3416/)

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Your example works perfect, but in side-by-side div only. i wanted it to work inline. i tried some modifications, but they don't work. maybe i made some errors, but can you please edit the answer to work inline, just for lesser work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you an unobtrusive way of writing javascript and used jquery as it is tagged in the question.

```js
$('#linkWrapper a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  $('.'+this.id).fadeIn().siblings('div:not(#linkWrapper)').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='linkWrapper'>
  <a href='#' id='div1'>Show Div 1</a>
  <a href='#' id='div2'>Show Div 2</a>
</div>
<div class='div1' style='display:none;'>div1</div>
<div class='div2' style='display:none;'>div2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You van sue these functions to make a fade effect.

```
    function unfade(element) { 
  var op = 0.1; // initial opacity  
  element.style.display = 'block'; 
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (op >= 1){
      clearInterval(timer); 
    } 
    element.style.opacity = op; 
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op += op * 0.1;
  }, 10); 
}

    function fade(element) {
  var op = 1; // initial opacity 
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (op <= 0.1){
      clearInterval(timer);      
      element.style.display = 'none'; 
    } 
    element.style.opacity = op; 
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")"; 
    op -= op * 0.1; 
  }, 50); 
}
```