# Image animation across the screen using only javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

I need to animate a picture from the top left of the screen to the bottom right of the screen. I can only use javascript. I made some research but everyone using CSS or Jquery for animation so I couldn't find answer for my question. So my questions are how can I determine the bottom right of the screen and how can I animate the picture exactly to that point?
I tried this but this just goes across the screen into infinity.
Here is my code:

```
     var imgObj = null;
     var animate;

     function init(){

        imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
        imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 

        imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
        imgObj.style.top = '0px'; 
      }
        function moveRight(){

         imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 1 + 'px';
         animate = setTimeout(moveRight,60); // call moveRight in 60msec
         imgObj.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) + 1 + 'px';

       }
```

Comment: Might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549789/animation-in-native-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple example here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xnuBO5RRrjjnMJZjkxEu

```
   (function(window){
       var imgLeft = 0, imgTop = 0;
       var imgObj, screenWidth, screenHeight, finalTop, finalLeft, 
           slope, imgHeight, imgWidth;

       var animateImage = function(){
           imgObj.style.left = imgLeft < finalLeft ? imgLeft + 'px' : finalLeft + 'px';
           imgObj.style.top = imgTop < finalTop ? imgTop + 'px' : finalTop + 'px';

           if(imgLeft !== finalLeft || imgTop !== finalTop){
               requestAnimationFrame(animateImage);
           }

           imgLeft++;
           imgTop += slope;
       };

       window.onload = function(){
           imgObj = document.getElementById('image');

           screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
           screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

           imgHeight = imgObj.offsetHeight;
           imgWidth = imgObj.offsetWidth;

           slope = (screenHeight - imgHeight) / (screenWidth - imgWidth);

           finalTop = screenHeight - imgHeight;
           finalLeft = screenWidth - imgWidth;

           requestAnimationFrame(animateImage);
       };
    })(window);
```

Like SeanOlson said, to get it to go to the specific corner no matter what the height you are going to have to decide how to increment your top and left positions. You can use time stamps and requestAnimationFrame to keep things smooth with no jutter.

There is a decent tutorial on requestAnimationFrame here: http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/

**Second Edit
I forgot to mention, in case you aren't aware rAF isn't available in older browsers. Paul Irish has a polyfill for it though:

http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect, I will go through the tutorial make further adjustments!

Comment: No problem, updated the answer with the slope calculation so the square will go in a straight line to the corner. The slope will have to be recalculated on screen size change if you want to be that specific, but you would just have to rerun the logic in the onload function

Answer (score 1):

"How can I determine the bottom right of the screen and how can I animate the picture exactly to that point?"

You get the dimensions of the display through the window object:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
```

Because you're positioning the picture by it's upper-left corner, the final position will be

```
var final_top = height - img_height;
var final_left = width - img_width;
```

Then you use a simple loop or perhaps a interval timer to move the image incrementally until it reaches those coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! So that's solves my problem for the screen determination, but I still don't know how to animate it with the loop or interval to that exact point. Sorry I am new to js as I mentioned above I couldn't find much info regarding js animation.

Comment: It's going to require a bit of arithmetic.  You'll need to know the size of your image and decide how you want to animate it, either moving the image by a fixed number of pixels per frame of by a fixed number of frames.  In other words, do you want to say move it 5px at a time, or do you want to complete the animation in say, 100 frames.